# Fetching first record from NDB datastore in GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm currently writing an application on the Google App Engine for Python. I want to fetch the first record in my datastore, but for some reason this won't work. This is how I'd do it in MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM MyClass LIMIT 1;
```

However since I'm new to NDB, I can't quite seem to wrap my head around how this works. I tried reading [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queryclass) for examples but they don't quite work.

This is the code I currently have:

```
from google.appengine.ext.ndb import Model as NdbModel
from google.appengine.ext.ndb import StringProperty


class Model(NdbModel):

    @classmethod
    def get_first(cls):
        """
        Get the first record in the model datastore
        :return: Model
        """
        try:
            return cls.query().fetch(1)[0]
        except IndexError:
            raise ModelException("No records found in [%s] datastore" % cls.__name__)


class MyClass(Model):
    foo = StringProperty()
    bar = StringProperty()

a = MyClass.get_first() # TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment
```

---

This is my full stack trace:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment
    at _store_value (/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py:1127)
    at _deserialize (/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py:1496)
    at _from_pb (/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py:3209)
    at pb_to_entity (/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py:691)
    at pb_to_query_result (/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py:201)
    at _process_results (/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_query.py:2980)
    at __query_result_hook (/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_query.py:2947)
    at get_result (/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py:613)
    at _on_rpc_completion (/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py:513)
    at _run_to_list (/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/query.py:995)
    at _help_tasklet_along (/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py:427)
    at get_result (/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py:383)
    at fetch (/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/query.py:1218)
    at positional_wrapper (/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/utils.py:160)
    at get_first (/base/data/home/apps/s~project-id/v1.395271489319521947/project/core/models/utils.py:55)
    at me (/base/data/home/apps/s~project-id/v1.395271489319521947/project/core/routes/api/v1/profile.py:22)
    at dispatch_request (/base/data/home/apps/s~project-id/v1.395271489319521947/lib/flask/app.py:1625)
    at full_dispatch_request (/base/data/home/apps/s~project-id/v1.395271489319521947/lib/flask/app.py:1639)
    at handle_user_exception (/base/data/home/apps/s~project-id/v1.395271489319521947/lib/flask/app.py:1544)
    at full_dispatch_request (/base/data/home/apps/s~project-id/v1.395271489319521947/lib/flask/app.py:1641)
    at wsgi_app (/base/data/home/apps/s~project-id/v1.395271489319521947/lib/flask/app.py:1988)
    at handle_exception (/base/data/home/apps/s~project-id/v1.395271489319521947/lib/flask/app.py:1567)
    at wsgi_app (/base/data/home/apps/s~project-id/v1.395271489319521947/lib/flask/app.py:1991)
    at __call__ (/base/data/home/apps/s~project-id/v1.395271489319521947/lib/flask/app.py:2000)
    at Handle (/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py:267)
```

Comment: Show the full traceback. But also note it's a mistake to think of the datastore as a normal database; the only concept of ordering is provided by the indexes.

Comment: I get `ValueError: No records found in [MyClass] datastore` (I replaced your undefined `ModelException` with `ValueError`). So your problem may lie somewhere else. Also - `first` would just mean first in the result list - if you mean something else by that you'd need to also provide some sorting rule.

Comment: @DanielRoseman added my stack trace

Comment: I got same error as @DanCornilescu

Comment: My guess is the record that does exist, may have had it's class definition change between the time it was put() and this code.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are trying to retrieve the data immediately after it is written to the Datastore which will not work unless you set the same `parent key` on each entity as stated in App Engine's [Storing Data in Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/getting-started/storing-data-datastore) document.

To create a `parent key`, you could write:

```
from google.appengine.ext.ndb import Key
parent_key = Key('my_data', 'version_1')
```

and when you create your entity you should pass the `parent key` to the `constructor`:

```
my_entity = MyKindClass(parent=parent_key, foo=foo_input, bar=bar_input)
```

Then, you query your database by passing the `parent_key` to `query` method of your `kind` class:

```
first_result = MyKindClass.query(
            ancestor=parent_key).order(-MyKindClass.created).get()
```

I think you are interested in getting the latest data, so I ordered the results using `order` method with `-` operator which orders data descendingly. In addition, I used `get` method instead of `fetch(1)` which returns the first query result or `None` if there is no data.

The full code will be:

```
import webapp2
from google.appengine.ext.ndb import (
    Model, StringProperty, DateTimeProperty, Key)


class MyKindClass(Model):
    foo = StringProperty()
    bar = StringProperty()
    created = DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)


parent_key = Key('my_data', 'version_1')


class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        foo_input = self.request.get('foo')
        bar_input = self.request.get('bar')
        if foo_input and bar_input:
            my_entity = MyKindClass(parent=parent_key,
                                    foo=foo_input, bar=bar_input)
            my_entity.put()

        first_result = MyKindClass.query(
            ancestor=parent_key).order(-MyKindClass.created).get()
        if first_result is not None:
            self.response.write('foo: %s, and bar: %s' %
                                (first_result.foo, first_result.bar))
        else:
            self.response.write('No data yet!')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

For more information, see App Engine's [The Python NDB Client Library Overview](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/) document.